# ASP.NET CORE displaying image set to instance of a property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a property

```
public class Robusta
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int CoffeeId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Origin {get;set;}
    public string ImagePath {get;set;}
}
```

I have `ImagePath` set as `~/images/imageName.jpg` in the database. `~/images/imageName.jpg` works and displays image in the `view` if I do `<img src="~/images/imageName.jpg" />` so I thought that if I set property to that string by making `ImagePath='~/images/imageName.jpg'` and in my View I displayed

```
<td>
    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagePath)" />
</td>
```

that it would work, but it does not display the image. How can I add the image as a property and display it? Because I have different images for every instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I add the image as a property and display it?

You can use [`Url.Content` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper.content?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to resolve a url for your Image file when you pass it the relative path, like below.

```
<td>
    @*<img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagePath)" />*@
    <img src="@Url.Content(item.ImagePath)" />
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.